# In Typescript, how can I define a void function which takes no argument and does nothing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How can I define a void function which takes no argument and does nothing? The following is what I have at the moment:

```js
const _ = () => {};
```

Is there a shorter or more appropriate way of achieving this? I need it for testing of a React application.

Comment: This is really the shortest you can have. If you use a library like Lodash, you might find a [noop function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#noop) but whether that's shorter or more convenient is up to debate.

Comment: One char shorter is this: `const _ = _ => {};` :)

Comment: That looks like it.

Comment: @VLAZ agreed. B̶t̶w̶,̶ ̶`̶_̶.̶n̶o̶o̶p̶(̶)̶`̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶e̶a̶r̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶v̶o̶i̶d̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶

Comment: @ToivoSäwén how come? The [source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L15760) is literally `function noop() { // No operation performed. }`

Comment: You're right, my mistake